# How to show image as product on other domain as advertising

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

As we know when we visit e-commerce site like amazon and see some product,
after some time if we go to some other domain like Facebook, we should see same amazon product showing on Facebook.

Can you please tell me, how it achieve?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Related to adverts.

Comment: I need to understand the concept of showing product which are user browsed on some domain like (Mi phone on Amazon).When same user switch to other domain,User should see same product in Advertising section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question got answered a hundret times :)
https://www.quora.com/How-does-Facebook-know-what-I-looked-at-on-Amazon